# Bash script creates symlink inside directory aswell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, symlink

I have a bash script:

```
    for file in `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`
    do
      old=`pwd`
      new=".${file##*/}"
      newfile="$old/${file##*/}"
      cd
      wd=`pwd`
      link="$wd/$new"
      ln -s -f $newfile $link
      cd $old
    done
```

This is meant to create a symlink in the user's home directory with '.' prepended to all the files and directories in the current working directory. This works fine, however, it also creates a symlink inside any sub directories to the same directory. E.G. foo will now have a link at ~/.foo and foo/foo.

Is there any way I can fix this?

EDIT: Thanks to Sameer Naik and dave_thompson_085 I have changed it up a bit, but the problem still persists even when a alternate directory is given as an argument. It isn't a problem with sub directories it is that two links are being made, one to ~/.foo123 and one to foo123/foo123 not a link is being made to ~/ for foo1 and foo1/foo2.

```
for file in `ls -l | grep -v total | awk '{print  $NF;}'`
do
    old=`pwd`
    wd=`cd $1 && pwd`
    new=".${file}"
    newfile="$wd/${file}"
    cd
    wd=`pwd`
    link="$wd/$new"
    ln -s -f $newfile $link
    cd $old
done
```

Comment: Without having tried to run this ... it will also work on all directories, as you include them in the find. Is that desired?

Comment: This might help: http://www.shellcheck.net/ and [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @tink it is for automating my dotfile install so i want it to work on everything in the directory

Comment: `for f in $PWD/*; do ln -s "$f" "$HOME/.${f##*/}"; done` -- with `dotglob` set if you want to include target files that are (already) dotfiles (which will become double dots!); if you want only files and not dirs make it `test -f "$f" && ln ...` PS: 'append' means added at the end; adding at the beginning is called (somewhat archly) 'prepend'

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I already have a script to remove dot on everything before upload to github so that is not an issue. My problem is that every directory after the link has been made, everything will be at the home directory with the dot prepended (thanks) to the file but every folder in the dotfile directory also has a link to that folder in it, e.g ~/.foo and foo/foo. Thanks for your help though, I might add this later.

Comment: If you want find to only find regular files, just add `-type f`

Comment: @WilliamPursell my problem isn't with the files it is finding, but the symlinks that it is making.

Comment: @Provessor If you restrict `find` so that it does not emit directory names, then the additional links will not get created.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want recurse into sub-directories, try using

```
for file in `ls -l | grep -v ^d | awk '{print $NF;}'`
```

or use `-type f` in find to exclude subdirectories